# Universal iOS app file managing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have written universal app and am not sure about code/file management. For example, I use file A (.h and .m) on iPhone app and file B (.h and .m) on iPad. If I export IPA file, I think both file A and file B will be there for both iPhone and iPad. Can I manage to exclude file A for iPad? It is also same for images. I have some images that is only used in iPhone. How can I exclude that?

Comment: I'm not sure if you really understand universal app... you submit only one app to the app store and this one will be delivered for both iphone and ipad users. so you have to offer all files for all device types.

Comment: why two files? only 2 storyboards... one .h & .m file...

Comment: Sorry. Please kindly just ignore about all those 2 file. Let say I have file1.png and file2.png (and probably many other). May I know how to make file1.png accessible on iPhone? Is it possible? If not, all resource must be shared for both iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a universal app, the bundle will always include all files.

If you do not want that build and distribute 2 different targets for iPhone and iPad and include only required files and classes.